# In Wishmaster 3: Diana’s father died when the family car exploded, after he rescued Diana. Was he able to save his wife (her mother)?

Tags: wishmaster

And if not, who was she cared for by, afterwards? She was a teenager in the movie, and flashbacks show the crash happened when she was a little girl.

Comment: The question is also partially about who took over raising Diana, this happened when she was a kid and she was in her teens by the time of the movie, so SOMEONE had to be looking after her. Maybe one or some of her relatives (aunts/uncles/grandparents)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's confirmed in the film that both of her parents died in the car crash.

> **Djinn:** Are you gonna fail your friend like you failed your parents? [beat] Failed them with your selfishness? [beat] With your childish whining and your cowardice **as they burned alive?**

There's no mention of what happened to her afterwards (e.g. who raised her). She just turns up in the subsequent scene all growed up.